# How to create an aliased string type in Python with additional annotated metadata for type annotations

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to create a type annotation that allows me to do something like this:

```
test_var: MyStringAlias['something'] = "abc"
```

so that I can add some additional metadata that can be used at runtime. The string `'something'` would de different for each use of the type annotation.

I have found `typing.Annotated` which would allow code like this:

```
test_var: Annotated[str, 'something'] = "abc"
```

But what I really want is effectively an alias of `Annotated` with the aliased type already set to `str`.

Is there a way to create something like this that would allow access to that metadata at runtime but also pass mypy?

EDIT:

To explain a little better, I'm trying to create a string annotation for inline syntax hi-lighting of source code with a multi line string. I have the basics of the other end working within VS Code but this is what I want to do with the syntax and have if pass MyPy:

```
my_var: Code['html'] = """
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1>Woo linline syntax hi lighting</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
"""
```

This can be easily made to work in a code editor with the syntax set by the parameter.

The fall back from this if it's not possible would be preset alias for html, javascript, css, ect. but that's not as elegant.

Comment: To access the annotation at runtime i wouldn't go for a type hint, but some sort of class that stores the string and the extra data. You can make that class behave like a string in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, however it needs to be a type annotation, going to modify question to explain why.

Comment: But why do you need the information at runtime?

Comment: The plan is that people could use the annotations to decide how to handle the strings. It would allow building an api similar to Vue.js single file components but with Python. So you would be able to specify a style variable with an annotation indicating it’s it’s CSS, SASS, SCSS, LESS. We could even have an annotation such as code[‘scss’, ‘scoped’] which could indicate to the css compiler / component framework to scope the css to the component, siloes to how front end frameworks do.

Comment: Also, to add, for what I’m experimenting with I originally looked at building a custom Python importer to handle a custom format (much closer to Vue.js) but decided it was better to explore this route as it’s more flexible outside the toolkit I’m building.